# Getting a 'version not compatible' error when running dart code in VS Code terminal on Windows - how to fix it?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I want to write code with dart on VS Code and when I run it (terminal) it gives me this message:
`"This version of C:\dartt\bin\dart.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher."`